# Perl concatenate name of an array with an existing value

Tags: perl

The question is like this:
I have a loop. And while I iterate this loop I want to create a number of arrays with the following names: `array1` `array2` `array3`...

I am wondering if there is a way to concatenate these names in perl
I tried something like this but I get an error

```
$i = 0;
while ($i <= 5) {
    @array . $i = ();
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you *can* do this, but no, you *should not* do this.

What you should do instead is use an array of references to *anonymous arrays*:

```
@arrayrefs = ();
$i = 0;
while ($i <= 5) {
    $arrayrefs[$i] = [];
    $i++;
}
```

or, more tersely:

```
@arrayrefs = ([], [], [], [], [], []);
```

---

But for completeness' sake . . . you *can* do this, by using "symbolic references":

```
$i = 0;
while ($i <= 5) {
    my $name = "array$i";
    @$name = ();
    $i++;
}
```

(of course, arrays default to the empty array anyway, so this isn't really needed . . .).

---

By the way, note that it's actually customary to use a *for loop* rather than a while loop for such simple cases. Either this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    ...
}
```

or this:

```
for $i (0 .. 5) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use hash,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;
for my $i (1 .. 5) {

  $hash{ "array$i" } = [];
}
```

Long story short: [`Why it's stupid to use a variable as a variable name`](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html)

Comment: Seems to me an AoA would make far more sense than an HoA here.